# Why PATH is automatically exported?

Tags: linux, shell

Put the following `a.sh` and `b.sh` to `/tmp/` and make them executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/tmp:$PATH
A=5
echo $A
echo $PATH
b.sh
```

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $A
echo $PATH
```

If we run `/tmp/a.sh`, the output is:

```
5
/tmp:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

/tmp:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

This output shows that `PATH` is exported automatically. The question is why.

Comment: `PATH` is already in the environment. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path